wordpress template deployment issue
I was trying to create a wordpress resource - selected azure services only option and it showed one option of "wordpress scalable ....". i tried creating that resource. and it gives me below error.
I am getting below error
YAML
Copy
The template request exceeds the quota limitations for one or more Microsoft.Network resources in the subscription. Please check details for information about each resource and contact support to increase the respective quota. (Code: TemplateExceedsResourceQuotaLimits)
YAML
Copy
Subscription 5d222a05-2a46-457d-b6cd-00f02680b7d2 has a quota of 10 for resources of type PublicIpAddress with sku Standard. Subscription currently has 8 resources and the template contains 3 new resources of the this type which exceeds the quota. Please contact support to increase the quota for resource type PublicIpAddress (Code: ResourceCountExceedsLimitDueToTemplate)
Subscription 5d222a05-2a46-457d-b6cd-00f02680b7d2 has a quota of 10 for resources of type PublicIpAddress with sku Standard. Subscription currently has 8 resources and the template contains 3 new resources of the this type which exceeds the quota. Please contact support to increase the quota for resource type PublicIpAddress (Code: ResourceCountExceedsLimitDueToTemplate)

Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Your subscription has a quota of 10 for PublicIpAddress resources with sku Standard, you currently have 8. The template you are trying to deploy requires 3 additional PublicIpAddress resources, which exceeds your quota.
First, verify that is correct, in the Azure portal, navigate to All services -> Networking -> Public IP addresses to view the current resources.
Once you've confirmed that, then you can request an increase in the quota for PublicIpAddress resources in your subscription, like this:
Navigate to Help + support -> New support request.
Under Issue type, select Service and subscription limits.
Fill in the required details, specifying the increase needed for PublicIpAddress resources with sku Standard.
Submit the request. They'll process your request and increase the quota.
If you do not want to wait for the quota increase, you can modify the template to reduce the number of PublicIpAddress resources it's using.
Edit the YAML (or JSON) template to reduce the count of PublicIpAddress resources or to use an existing resource if possible.
If there are any unused PublicIpAddress resources, consider deleting them to free up space within your current quota.
Navigate to All services -> Networking -> Public IP addresses, select any unused addresses, and delete them.
Good luck!

Thank you for the answer with complete explanation.
